# I am new to ASN.1 coding. I am trying to create parse data from a ASN.1 format, replace values to the tag and regenerate a file in same format

Tags: java, asn.1

This is my input template:

```
headerValue ProfileElement ::= header : { 
major-version 2, 
minor-version 0, 
profileType "GSMA Profile Package", 
iccid '89019990001234567893'H, 
eUICC-Mandatory-services { 
usim NULL, 
milenage NULL, 
javacard NULL }, 
eUICC-Mandatory-GFSTEList { 
-- see Note 1 
id-MF, 
id-USIM }, 
-- These SMS connectivity parameters may be freely changed 
connectivityParameters 'A0090607#TON_NPI#DIALING_NUMBER'H }
```

I need the output file in same format but with new values for ICCID which will be generated dynamically by JAVA code

Comment: What do you want to do with the result ? I'm asking that because what you show is an ASN.1 value (usually only used for specifying or documenting).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jASN1](https://www.openmuc.org/asn1/download/) library available for java. Pass your data to it and get the parsed object list. There after, you can change the iccid value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need also to convert in DER coding ? If so, I would suggest to use Nokalva OSS library to create the object hierarchy in Java and then convert in DER.

If you don't need the DER coding, a simple trick we sometime use is to put a placeholder like you did in the #TON_NPI and make a search / replace with Java.

PS: of course if you update ICCID in ProfileHeader you need to update also content of 2FE2 under MF (that is actually more important)

Answer (score 0):

What you have quoted is the part of ASN.1 module definitions of embedded [UICC(eUICC) Interoperable Format Technical Specification](http://simalliance.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Profile-interoperability-technical-specification_V1-0.pdf) published by SIM Alliance.

After collecting all ASN.1 definitions starting from section 7.3 in a one file as module definition, it can be compiled with any free or commercial java ASN.1 compiler. Java sources generated for data types and encode/decode run-time library of ASN.1 compiler can be embedded to your application to generate ASN.1 encoded byte stream for Profile Element.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with a commercial (not free) solution, Objective Systems has a tool called [ASN2TXT](https://www.obj-sys.com/products/asn2txt/pricing.php) which will perform a transformation from what you have **A**SN.1 **V**alue **N**otation (AVN) to DER and other encodings.  It can also perform a transformation in the reverse direction so that you can get AVN from a DER-encoded profile package.  The tool can be run from the command line (no software development required), or you can use the .so/.dll libraries from your own code.

For eSIM profile generation, you can first use the tool to transform a profile package template from AVN to XER, personalize the profile package using XPath, and then transform the XER representation to DER for upload to the SM-DP+.

*I do not work for Objective Systems - just a happy customer.*